# Is it possible to detect geoposition of client in WCF C#?

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0

How I can get geoposition of clients connected to WCF Service from others devices and tracking too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All "accurate" geo-positioning would have to be opt-in on the client, and your client would have to send this information down to your WCF service as part of the request.

WCF generally equates to a web service call at the endpoint (so, an http request). IP address is generally in the header.  As you've probably seen in other applications, you can get a very broad location based on that (such as the city).